# El código no devuelve nada

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main() {
     char riperino;
     int cantPalabras;
     procesarPalabras(&riperino, &cantPalabras);
     printf("La cantidad de palabras es: %d", cantPalabras);
     return 0; 
 }

 void procesarPalabras(char *riperino, int *cantPalabras) {
     printf("Ingrese una palabra:");
     scanf("%c",&riperino);
     while(riperino != '.') {
         *cantPalabras++;
         scanf("%c", &riperino);
         if(riperino == ' ')
         {
             *cantPalabras--;
         }
     } 
 }
```

No me queda bien en claro como pasar los parametros por referencia, alguien me puede explicar:

1. Por que este codigo no devuelve nada?
2. Los asteriscos y ampersand van en las estructuras de control tambien?
   Gracias

Comment: C no soporta parametros por referencia, solo es _"mimica"_ con punteros, [Esta pregunta de SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c) te puede ayudar.

Comment: O sea que lo unico que hago es pasar el valor al puntero, bien
Igual sigo con la duda de por que no devuelve nada, se solucionaria si pongo lo del while en otro modulo?

Comment: Si mejoras el título tendrás mejores respuestas. En la página principal donde aparecen todas las dudas con sus títulos no se sabe que problemas tienes. Especifica un poco más.  Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Edité mi respuesta para que hiciera lo que querías.

> Lo que faltaba para que el código para que hiciera lo que pides, primero que tu variable `riperino` donde guardas las palabras sea un arreglo de carácteres para almacenar toda la palabra. Ahora cuando llamas la función que procesa la palabra ya no mandas la variable con el ampersand puesto que es un arreglo y los arreglos son punteros en C. `procesarPalabras(riperino, &cantPalabras);`. Solo mandas por referencia la variable entera que contara las palabras usando el `&`. Ya dentro de la función pides la palabra `gets( riperino );` y recorres el puntero de esta forma `riperino++;` sumando una posición al puntero por cada iteración hasta encontrar el carácter punto `while(*riperino != '.')`. Y durante el proceso de recorrer la letra por letra comparas si es espacio restas de lo contrario sumas.

Espero que te sirva para aprender y no solo para hacer tu tarea.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  void procesarPalabras(char *riperino, int *cantPalabras);

  int main() {
      char riperino[100];
      int cantPalabras = 0;
      procesarPalabras(riperino, &cantPalabras);
      printf("La cantidad de palabras es: %d", cantPalabras);
      return 0; 
  }

  void procesarPalabras(char *riperino, int *cantPalabras) {
      printf("Ingrese una palabra:");
      gets( riperino );
      while(*riperino != '.') {
         if (*riperino == ' ') {
              (*cantPalabras)--;
          } else {
              (*cantPalabras)++;
          }
          riperino++;
      }
  }
```

Tu código en realidad no devuelve nada por que el tipo que regresa es vacío (Si es a lo que te refieres con **no devuelve nada**) pero como mandas la referencia de las variables `riperino` y `cantPalabras` se modifican cuando regrese la función, si no mandaras la referencia las variables quedarían intactas ya que se copiarían cuando se manden a la función

Y sí se necesita el asterisco en la estructura de control (while) ya que le índicas que lo que quieres comparar es el contenido de tu puntero por que `riperino` dentro de tú función es un puntero y el "contenido" es decir a lo que apunta se accede con `*` que es el carácter que en realidad quieres comparar.

Y pues de los detalles que encontré solo te faltaba inicializar `cantPalabras` y a los `scanf` como ya tus variables son referencia no se necesita el `&` además como ya mencione poner `*riperino` cuando comparas

Comment: No funciona u.u lo que deberia hacer el codigo es contar la cantidad de caracteres hasta que encuentra un punto y en caso de encontrar un espacio restarlo, hasta ahora devuelve 0 caracteres asi que debe ser porque es un void no? Soy muy nuevo programando

Comment: Ya edité mi respuesta anterior para que el código haga lo que dices, espero que te sirva para aprender y no solo lo copies y pegues para tu tarea

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar los valores por referencia en lenguaje C, tus variables deben ser punteros, los cuales hacen referencia o **apuntan** a una seccion de la memoria ram donde se encuentra almacenado el dato de la variable. Luego en la función `procesarPalabras(riperino, cantPalabras);` sólo pasas los punteros

```
 int main() {
     char *riperino;
     int  *cantPalabras;
     procesarPalabras(riperino, cantPalabras);
     printf("La cantidad de palabras es: %d", cantPalabras);
     return 0; 
 }
```

De hecho en la definición de la función `procesarPalabras` estas recibiendo dos punteros

`void procesarPalabras(char *riperino, int *cantPalabras) {...}`

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Es verdad, pero también la forma en la que se esta haciendo en la pregunta es correcta, se puede pasar como parámetro la dirección de la variable, ya que las direcciones también son punteros y por lo tanto también esta pasando la variable por referencia

Answer (score 1):

**¿Por qué tu programa no imprime nada?**

`scanf` necesita punteros a variables para obrar su magia. Si revisamos tu código tenemos lo siguiente:

```
void procesarPalabras(char *riperino, int *cantPalabras);
```

Es decir, tanto `reperino` como `cantPalabras` son punteros y por ese motivo no es necesario hacer uso del operador de referencia `&` al llamar a `scanf`:

```
scanf("%c", riperino);
```

Por otro lado, `riperino` no es una variable que estés usando fuera de la función `procesarPalabras`. Salvo que esto sea debido a cambios realizados en el código con la única finalidad de mostrar tu problema (cosa que dudo porque la variable la usas repetidas veces dentro de un bucle), esa variable debería ser local de la función:

```
 void procesarPalabras(int *cantPalabras) {
     char riperino;
     printf("Ingrese una palabra:");
     scanf("%c",&riperino); // Como ahora no es un puntero hay que usar &
     while(riperino != '.') {
         *cantPalabras++;
         scanf("%c", &riperino);
         if(riperino == ' ')
         {
             *cantPalabras--;
         }
     } 
 }
```

** ¿Cuándo hay que usar & y *? **

`&` es el operador de referencia, es decir, permite obtener una referencia a una variable. En C las referencias son punteros:

```
int var = 0;
int* ptr = &var;
*ptr = 5;
printf"(%d %d",var,*ptr);
```

Si aplicamos el operador `&` a un puntero simple obtendremos un puntero doble. Si se lo aplicamos a un puntero doble obtenemos un puntero triple y así.

En C si usamos una variable por valor estaremos accediendo al valor almacenado por dicha variable... si la variable resulta ser un puntero el valor que almacena es la posición de memoria apuntada por dicha variable:

```
int var = 1;
char *ptr = &var;
printf("%d %d", var, ptr); // El segundo valor es una posición de memoria
```

El operador `*` sirve, en el caso de los punteros, para acceder no a la dirección de memoria apuntada sino al valor almacenado en dicha posición de memoria:

```
int var = 1;
int* ptr = &var;
int var2 = (int)ptr; // copiamos la dirección de memoria
int var2 = *ptr; // copiamos el valor almacenado en la posición de memoria

printf("%d %d %d", var, var2, var3);
```

Un saludo.